Conditional central limit theorem
Let $\{S_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a centered random walk with real values and i.i.d. increments $X_i$ with $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0 ,\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = 1$. I'm having problems in studying limits of the form:
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(S_m\in A \Bigl|\bigcap_{k = 1}^{m-1}S_k\in B_k)
$$
where $A,B_k\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and the sequence of probabilities $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{k = 1}^{m-1}S_k\in B_k)$ approaches $0$ as $m\to\infty$.
By CLT we know that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(S_m\in A) = \mathbb{P}(N\in C)$ where $N\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, is it possible to conclude something about the limit above? Is there a conditional version of the central limit theorem I could use to solve this? More hypothesis are needed? Thank you in advance for your help.

Your indices are a bit confusing. What is the $k$ index for $B$? Is there some significance to it? Also I believe the $S_k$ in the condition should be $S_i$.

Thank you @LSK21 I fixed it! Anyway this is my particular case where I am conditioning to that intersection event. Although it is not strictly necessary, in the sense that I'm interested in solving limits of the form $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(S_m\in A \Bigl|E_m)$ where $E_m$ is a sequence of events such that $\lim_{m\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_m) = 0$. This limit is equal to $\mathbb{P}(N\in C)$? Or depends on the events $E_m$?

By $S_n$ do you mean the rescaled sum of the increments? With you definition the CLT states that $\lim_n \mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \in A) = \mathbb{P}(N \in A)$
